# Logic to show or hide element using angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

so I got some problem in logic to show or hide the element.

I have this function to show or hide the "span" element, by that I can show different color on each text.

```
startWritting() {
// const spanOne = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('one');
// const spanTwo = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('two');
// const spanThree = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('three');
// const spanFour = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('four');

const durCharFwd = 0.1; // character typed
const durFullGap = 2000; // time between typed/delete
const durCharBwd = 0.8; // character deleted
const durDoneGap = 1000;
let strings = ['Your value', 'Organic', 'Gluteen-free', 'Fair-trade'];
let durTotal;
setInterval(() => {
  strings.forEach((string, i) => {
    durTotal =
      string.length * (durCharFwd + durCharBwd) + durFullGap + durDoneGap;
    setInterval(() => {
      this.elements.forEach((el, index) => {
        if (index === i) {
          el.isSelected = true;
        } else {
          el.isSelected = false;
        }
      });
    }, durTotal);
  });
}, durTotal);
```

}

and heres my HTML code

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let el of elements">
        <span
          *ngIf="el.isSelected"
          [id]="el.id"
          class="animated-text"
        ></span>
      </ng-container>
```

Bytheway this is to edit the element on typewritting animation as you can see the full html and css animation code here
https://codepen.io/matadantelinga/pen/ExQeqjj
I wonder if anyone here can advise me on the logic??

Comment: If the goal is to modify an element's style properties it's probably better to use the `[ngClass]` binding (or it's cousin, `[ngStyle]`).

Comment: The user is asking about Hide and Show Element not Modify Element Styles. You can hide and show via CSS but that's pointless since you have the built-in html hidden property you can use with Angular property binding as you can use *ngIf=""

Comment: What's the error you're getting to start with ?

Comment: hi guys I updated my question as it is also has relation on css typewritter animation, so basically I want to edit the color on each text that is inside the span pseudo elements.

Comment: Hi @temp_user so the text didnt show up correctly, it is only showing the first span / text element, actually it is loop, each element is do show / hide, but I cannot get the right duraction, e.g I want to show "ABC" in red color, and after the typewritting animation is finished, it will hide the "ABC" and it will show another text "BCD" for example with diferent color.

I hope that make sense

Comment: hi @Walid yes I already use *ngIf and make it hide / show by the boolean property on each data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does something like that helps ?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cr9lq4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

```js
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  text = '';
  color = '';

  texts = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'];
  colors = ['cyan', 'lightgreen', 'salmon', 'coral'];

  constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    timer(0, 500)
      .pipe(map((i) => i % 4))
      .subscribe((i) => {
        this.text = this.texts[i];
        this.color = this.colors[i];
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
      });
  }
}
```

**EDIT** Added the typer to the stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cr9lq4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: Hi @temp_user thanks! I tried your solution and modify it litle bit, and its work now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just declare an array colors

```
colors=['red','blue','yellow','green']
```

Just only add `[style.color]="colors[i%colors.length]"`

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let el of elements;let i=index">
        <span *ngIf="el.isSelected"
          [style.color]="colors[i%colors.length]"
          [id]="el.id"
          class="animated-text"
        ></span>
</ng-container>
```